# Why is Invalid memory access exception thrown occasionally?

Tags: java, c, exception, native, jna

I have the a JNA structure which is throwing InvalidMemoryAccessException occasionally. Without changing the code,when I run it, it runs at times. At times it throw the exception as shown below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.getInt(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getInt(Pointer.java:602)
at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getValue(Pointer.java:390)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.readField(Structure.java:653)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.read(Structure.java:521)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.autoRead(Structure.java:1882)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.conditionalAutoRead(Structure.java:491)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:418)
```

Shown below is my structure in C.

```
 RFIDLIB_API ipj_error start(
    ipj_iri_device* iri_device       /*[in]*/,
    ipj_action      action           /*[in]*/);

 typedef uint32_t ipj_action;
```

Below is my Java implementation.

```
public class ipj_action extends Structure {

public int ipj_action_value;

public ipj_action() {
    setAlignType(Structure.ALIGN_NONE);
    allocateMemory();
    read();
}

@Override
protected List getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("ipj_action_value");

}

}
```

Below is the main class from where I call it.

```
public class RFIDMain {

public  rfidlib rlib;
public  ipj_iri_device ipj_iri_device;
public  ipj_action ipj_action;
public  ipj_error errorStatus;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    RFIDMain r = new RFIDMain();


    r.rlib = (rfidlib) Native.loadLibrary("rfidlib", rfidlib.class);
    r.ipj_iri_device = new ipj_iri_device();
    r.ipj_action = new ipj_action();
    r.errorStatus = new ipj_error();
    r.ipj_action.ipj_action_value = 0x1;

    r.errorStatus = r.rlib.start(r.ipj_iri_device, r.ipj_action);

    System.out.println(r.errorStatus);
}

}
```

The exception is not thrown when I make any modification to the line "r.ipj_action.ipj_action_value=0x01". Like if I remove it and run it, it runs. If I put it after removing and run again it runs. If I keep it as it is and run it throws the exception. Like if I keep the code without that line and run twice, the exception is thrown. Similarly if I keep the code with that line and run twice again the exception is throw. Is this some problem with the memory allocation for the structure? Please advice.

Comment: can u tell me where is C in it.

Comment: i dont know about garbage collection in java. But u should free the memory of r object in there in the main function.

Comment: In java garbage collection is done automatically. But I did try forcing a manual garbage collection using System.gc() method. But still the exception keeps coming.

Comment: @KishanKumar I have edited the question. Please read the last paragraph. Do you get any idea? :(

Comment: i think it is trying to allocate the new object over the old memory, which is causing the problem.